# IE8 - How can I remove extra padding from an image?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, padding

See this image:

[image]

for a clearer understanding of what's happening to the header graphic.

I've added the interconnect solutions worldwide logo to the orange banner through a customized joomla module; I did this to make editing and updating easier.

But this resulted in adding extra padding to the top in IE8 - it collapses and is fine in IE7

How do I remove this extra padding?

I’ve tried lots of different css but nothing seems to pin point the issue.

```
#header-bot .moduletableisw .isw  
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;!important'
    padding-top: 0px;!important'
}
```

I’ve managed to figure out most issues I’ve had with css, but this one’s got me.

Hopefully there will be a simple solution?

Comment: Your image is not accessible without signing in there.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible for images to have padding

Comment: The image is private even if logged in.

Comment: Google search for "image hosting" http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=image+hosting&aq=0&oq=image+host&aqi=g10..  I used third result and upload image there

Comment: @Dave - yes, images can have padding: I use it often to give them a "framed" effect, with a border and a background colour.

Comment: Hi, didn't mean to be impolite with the title in uppercase... Not sure how to change it. I'm new to this site and haven't quite got my bearings.

I've made the image public so everyone should be able to see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For starters your CSS is invalid, it should be:

```
#header-bot .moduletableisw .isw  
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

(You can remove the `px` when the size is zero.)

Also check for margin/padding on the parent element(s) such as `.moduletableisw` and also any spacing on sibling elements.

Posting your HTML would help.